# Escaping characters in (s)printf with atom-editor

Tags: f#, mono, printf, atom-editor

I am having difficulties escaping '\' in sprintf statements when working with atom editor on Linux with mono.

On Windows with VS:

```
sprintf "%s" "\\"
```

is evaluated to

```
val it : string = "\"
```

as it should.

If I evaluate the same expression with VSCode or atom-editor under Linux I get

```
val it : string = "\\"
```

Further Remark:
If on Windows (I installed Mono on Windows to check this out) I start 'fsharpi' from the 'Mono Command Prompt' the said expression is evaluated correctly as "\". As it does when I do the same thing under Linux.

Comment: I think it might be a fluke of how FSI displays values. What happens if you replace `sprintf` with `printfn`?

Comment: printfn "\\" and printfn "%s" "\\" both print '\\' instead of '\'

Comment: Super weird. That totally looks like a bug. Does it happen if you compile the code, too? If so, can you look at the resulting assembly with ILSpy and see what string ends up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like an editor display issue than like a bug in the evaluation itself. To be fair, this always confuses me - should the editor display the string value as it is, or should it display it as a valid escaped F# string? I think both would make sense...

The easiest way to check what value you're really getting is to run a few checks in F# Interactive:

```
> let s = "\\";;    
val s : string = "\"

> s.Length;;
val it : int = 1

> s.[0] = '\\';;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: yes, it seems to be an editor display issue/feature.

Comment: In a comment above, you state that printing the string with `printfn` also results in a double slash and not a single one. The way `printfn` works most definitely has nothing to do with FSI display logic, does it?

Comment: yes, I agree it shouldn't. It works as it should in the console but not when evaluated interactively within atom-editor. So in that sense I think it is an issue of how atom-editor represents the console..